# Bash retrieve column number from column name

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Is there a better way (such as a one liner in AWK) where I can get the column number in a table with headings from a column name?  I want to be able to process a column independent of what the column number actually is (such as when another column is added the script will not need to change).

For example, given the following table in "table.tsv":

```
ID  Value   Target  Not Used
1   5   9   11
2   4   8   12
3   6   7   10
```

I can do a sort on the "Target" column using:

```
#!/bin/bash
(IFS=$'\t'; read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; i=0; for col in $REPLY; do
    ((++i))
    [ "$col" == "Target" ] && break
done; sort -t$'\t' "-k$i,${i}n") < table.tsv
```

Is there a way to do it without the for loop (or at least clean it up a little)?

The expected output of the given script is:

```
ID      Value   Target  Not Used
3       6       7       10
2       4       8       12
1       5       9       11
```

However, I was trying to give an example of what I was trying to do.  I want to pass/filter my table through several programs so the headings and all columns should be preserved:  just have processing occur at each step.
In pseudo code, what I would like to do is:

```
print headings from stdin
i=$(magic to determine column position given "Target")
sort -t$'\t' "-k$i,${i}n"  # or whatever processing is required on that column
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

another alternative with a lot of pipes

```
$ head -1 table | tr -s ' ' '\n' | nl -nln |  grep "Target" | cut -f1
```

extract first row, transpose, number lines, find column name, extract number

Or, `awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS='\t' '/Target/{print NR; exit}' file.tsv
3
```

Comment: The `awk` approach is really slick! Just one thing to add - you might want to explicly define start and end of the column name you're trying to match.
Like so: `awk -v RS='\t' '/^Target$/{print NR; exit}' file.tsv`
Otherwise, depending on the names of your columns, you risk an unwanted sub-string match with another column.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an awk alternative:

```
awk -F '\t' -v col='Target' 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == col){c=i; break}}
      {print $c}' file
```

---

**EDIT:** To print column number only:

```
awk -F '\t' -v col='Target' 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==col) {print i;exit}}' file
3
```

Comment: While that works, I am mostly focused on returning the column number:  see the i=$(magic...) line I edited into my question.

Comment: ok check updated answer to print column number for the given name.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v name='Target' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==name) print i; exit}' file
3
```