# How to find the position of word in a list of string to use in awk?

Tags: awk, count, grep, position

Morning guys,

I often have files that I want to grep+awk but that have a lot of fields. 
I'm interested in one in particular (so I'd like to `awk '{print $i}'`) but how can I know what position (ie "i" here) my column is, other than counting it manually?

With files of around 70 fields, I'd be saving lot of time! :)

Thanks a lot,

[Edit]

Following Ian McGowan's suggestion, I'll look for the column number in the file's header:

```
head -1 myFile | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%3d=%s\n", i, $i); }' | grep -i <the_column_Im_looking_for>
```

Thanks everyone,

Will1v

Comment: `echo hey there|awk '{print index($0,"there")}'` will return `5` , hope it helps.

Comment: What is the condition to find the column you want?

Comment: Please post a sample text along with expected output.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to know which position a certain keyword is (not the index), so for instance, if the header of my file is:

`Shape Colour Price`

I'd like to grep the header, and if I'm looking for the "Price" column, I'd like to have "3" returned (rather than "14", which `echo "Shape Colour Price" | awk '{print index($0, "Price")}'` would give me).

I'd then know I can `echo myFile | awk '{print $3}'`.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32612859/2088135

Comment: It does actually. 
`awk -v RS='\t' '/Target/{print NR; exit}' file.tsv` and `head -1 table | tr -s ' ' '\n' | nl -nln |  grep "Target" | cut -f1` are nice ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a sample but:

```
$ cat > file
this is
the sample
$ awk '{ 
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i=="sample")
            print NR,i 
}' file
2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time when trying to profile some large text delimited file.

```
$head -4 myfile
4A      1       321     537     513.30
4B      0.00
8       592     846     905.66
9B2     39      887     658.77
```

Transpose or pivot by looping over the columns/fields:

```
$awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%4d %3d=%s\n", NR, i, $i); }' < myfile
   1   1=4A
   1   2=1
   1   3=321
   1   4=537
   1   5=513.30
   2   1=4B
   2   2=0.00
   3   1=8
   3   2=592
   3   3=846
   3   4=905.66
   4   1=9B2
   4   2=39
   4   3=887
   4   4=658.77
```

You can add `printf("row=%-4d col=%-3d:%s\n", NR, i, $i);` or whatever in the format mask for printf, and then grep for just the data you care about to find out the column, or if you know the columns grep for col=44 to get the 44th column.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a built in option to count straight away, but that's pretty good, thanks Ian!

Comment: One other suggestion is to turn the "column" reference from 1,2,3... to A,B,C... etc. which looks a little bit more like an excel cell reference.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs -n1` will print the columns one per line, so you can do this:

```
head -1 file | xargs -n1 | grep -n "column_name"
```